# Missing required parameters for [Route: siswa.edit] [URI: siswa/{siswa}/edit]. (View: D:\SIM-Rapot\resources\views\siswa\edit.blade.php)

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to edit data (i click edit button) in laravel using route resource, but always getting error. I've stuck for hours

**Controller**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $siswa = Siswa::find($id);
    return view('siswa.edit', compact('siswa'));
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach ($siswa as $item)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $item->nis }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $item->nama_siswa }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $item->rombel }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $item->rayon_id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $item->jurusan_id }}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="{{route('siswa.edit', $item->id)}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" type="button">Edit</a>
                                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="button">Hapus</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
```

**Route**

```
Route::resource('siswa', 'SiswaController');
```

Sorry for my bad English and thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the path is siswa/{siswa}/edit, which means that it waiting for an object Siswa as parameter. If you want to use $id instead, you have to define the route by yourself.

```
Route::get('siswa/{id}/edit', 'SiswaController@edit');
```

Comment: Can i still use route resource?